# WPF binding IsEnabled not working (inner DataContext)

Tags: c#, wpf, data-binding

I have dialog window with properties, in xaml I put:

```
DataContext="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}}">
```

and trying to bind `Grid`'s *IsEnabled* to property that resist in my dialog class, as so:

```
//xaml
<Grid Margin="10,0,0,10" Name="DevicePropertiesGrid" IsEnabled="{Binding Path=isFixedMode}">

//source
public bool isFixedMode 
{ 
    get { return ModeComboBox.SelectionBoxItem.ToString().Equals("Fixed"); } 
}
```

no result, *isFixedMode* switching it's value, but no effect on the `Grid`.

Comment: You aren't notifying WPF that the property value has changed. You need to implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` and fire the `PropertyChanged` event *when the property changes*. But since you seem to be binding it to the a combobox anyway, it would make a lot more sense to just bind it to the combo box.

Comment: @Mr.B You don't need a setter for what would inherently be a one-way binding.

Comment: Binding reads value of `isFixedMode` only once and doesn't react to changes, because `isFixedMode` property doesn't notify about changes (it has only getter, w/o setter). it seems simpler to implement a trigger for grid based on `ModeComboBox.SelectionBoxItem` value (if  ModeComboBox.SelectionBoxItem is a DependencyProperty it *will* notify about changes)

Comment: @Ash, it has a getter, but no setter. Having a setter isn't a requirement however, it just needs to raise a `PropertyChanged` event when it changes (which doesn't *have* to be in a setter, that's just usually the most convenient place to put it).

Comment: @MattBurland, of course i meant getter, it was a typo. i agree your comments about `INPC`. but if a window is used as its own `DataContext` and then one has to implement `INPC` in window  for notifications, then it is time to create a separate ViewModel

Comment: @ASh: I don't disagree there. The OP needs to look into how the MVVM model is supposed to work. The combobox should be bound to a property in the VM and `IsFixedMode` should exist in the VM too.

Comment: I would recommend using an [IValueConverter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.ivalueconverter(v=vs.110).aspx) rather then a property on the view model since this seams like it's only relevant to the view and this sort of stuff makes your ViewModel less testable and readable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to [notify](http://www.daedtech.com/wpf-and-notifying-property-change/) your view when the value is updated.

In your case I would probably write classic get/set property, and update it when my selection item changed.

Of course your ViewModel has to be *INotifyPropertyChanged*. Then you can do something like:

```
    private bool _isFixedMode;
    public bool IsFixedMode 
    {
        get { return _isFixedMode; }
        set
        {
            _isFixedMode= value;
            if(PropertyChanged != null)
                PropertyChange(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsFixedMode ")); 
        }
    }
```

Then you register to the event *OnSelectionBoxItemChanged*, and everytime it's called, you re-set the IsFixedMode value like this:

```
   IsFixedMode = ModeComboBox.SelectionBoxItem.ToString().Equals("Fixed");
```

Answer (score 1):

Since I mentioned IValueConverter Here is how in my opinion how this scenario should be done.
Code in the xaml

```
<StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Resources>
            <local:IsFixedValueConverter x:Key="IsFixedValueConverter"/>
        </StackPanel.Resources>
        <ComboBox Margin="10" Width="120" SelectedValue="{Binding SelectionItem}">
            <sys:String>Fixed</sys:String>
            <sys:String>NotFixed</sys:String>
        </ComboBox>

        <CheckBox Margin="10" Width="120"  IsChecked="{ Binding SelectionItem, Converter={ StaticResource IsFixedValueConverter} }"/>

        <TextBox Margin="10" Width="120"  IsEnabled="{ Binding SelectionItem, Converter={ StaticResource IsFixedValueConverter } }"/>

    </StackPanel>
```

And the C# code

```
 public partial class MainWindow : Window
    {
        //The window is just so we have something to set a VM on if you DataContext is Self you can add the ViewModel code to the UI element (But you really should use ViewModels)
        public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = new VM();
        }


    }

    public class VM:INotifyPropertyChanged 
    {
        private string selectionItem = IsFixedValueConverter.IS_FIXED;
        public string SelectionItem 
        {
            get { return selectionItem; }
            set
            {
                selectionItem = value;
                if (PropertyChanged != null)//If you are using c# 6 use nameof(SelectionItem) rather than "SelectionItem"
                    PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs("SelectionItem"));
            }
        }

        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    }

    public class IsFixedValueConverter : IValueConverter 
    {
        public const string IS_FIXED = "Fixed";

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return value!= null?value.ToString() == IS_FIXED:false;
        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            return ((bool)value) ? IS_FIXED : null;
        }
    }
```

This is just a recommendation